# Configure HA Proxy with two application servers to handle fail-over

Tags: java, web-applications, haproxy, high-availability

I have configured two application servers with HA Proxy to recover from fail-over situation.
So I want to configure HA in such a way that if my 1st application server goes down, then only next requests forward to 2nd server, otherwise 2nd server must be seat as ideal only. I know that I am trying to disable actual purpose of HA Proxy, but that's what my requirement. My 2nd server is busy with other jobs and will help to serve request only if 1st server crashed. I will loose all sessions  from 1st server but that is OK for me.

Is it possible through HA Proxy configurations? Please let me know.

Comment: Well, I found this in 2 mins of googling... http://blog.haproxy.com/2014/01/17/emulating-activepassing-application-clustering-with-haproxy/

Comment: Thanks Florent. This link solves my problem. I too googled but may be with other words.